# How to verify whether tensorflow 1.4's tf.data.Dataset is starved?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm doing a number of `dataset.map(...)` calls that are run in parallel. My GPU isn't running at 100% and I suspect that the preprocessing pipeline is to blame.

How can I validate that the pipeline is not starved prior to a training step, and thus warn the user of the condition?

My final dataset transformation is `dataset.prefetch(2)` which prefetches 2 full batches.

For example, I'd hope to do:

```
sess.run(iterator.is_ready)
```

or

```
sess.run(dataset.buffer_size)
```